# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Lenovo Ideapad u300s

Tags: 12.04, lenovo, compatibility, ideapad

I want to buy a Lenovo Ideapad U300s Ultrabook.

Is it compatible with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

(Intel Core i7-2677M, 4GB, 256GB SSD)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me I would say I don't know why it would have a problem. Testing the laptop with an Ubuntu LiveCD will give you an answer quickly. If you can test it in the place where you are buying the laptop great. If not, when it arrives test the laptop.

But there are a couple of issues still present (At least in 12.04).I have also added some links of some old posts and bugs (That affected 11.04 and 11.10) that you might want to check and the ones that affect 12.04:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1889596&page=6
(11.04 and 11.10 users. most problems were hardware problems and not Ubuntu)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/974455
(Suggest to do a BIOS Firmware upgrade)

http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&DocID=HT073063
(BIOS upgrade)

http://www.linlap.com/lenovo_ideapad_u300s
(Users confirming problem with 12.04 (And other distros like Fedora)

In general there are 3 problems detected:

- Suspend/Resume does not work correctly.
  (There is a fix for this already)
- Touchpad functionality is not working properly. Recognized as a generic PS/2 mouse.
  (Fix for this is on it's way)
- Some keys like <kbd>T</kbd> or any of the Arrow keys do not work correctly. Although this problem is more related to a hardware problem by many users. There is even some that have fixed the problem by either upgrading their BIOS or draining the battery completely (Again, more related to hardware than a system since it also happens on Windows).

I would recommend to either, wait for 13.04 or apply 12.10. Any of this 2 will have less probability to have any of this 3 bugs. Also verify the keys when the laptop arrives just to check that all keys are working correctly. Then simply test Ubuntu using the LiveCD or LiveUSB. Will save you the trouble of installing it and getting any error (If any appear in your case. Remember the problems mentioned do not happen to all users, only some).

For some additional information here are 2 positive links:

[Stuart Langridge testing the Lenovo U300s](https://plus.google.com/108243663090085262773/posts/C6KG4hz26TM)
(Several tips by Stuart)

[Ubuntu Friendly with the Lenovo U310](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/12.04/LENOVO/IdeaPad%20U310/i%3aBKI%3aDbiOWp%3aFm%3aI8g%3aDnZ%3aB9ip%3ao%3aB5G%3aDUq%3aB9i/)
(Could not find the U300s)

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu on a Lenovo ideapad U300s has still this serious bug active:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/974455

This bug causes some keys to permanently send other keys codes after using the machine for a while. Once the problem happens, the keyboard malfunction affects also the BIOS screen and any other OS installed. The ultrabook works fine on Windows (the only OS supported by Lenovo for this model) and once the bug appears (that only happens on Linux) it also affects the Windows instalation.

The only way to reset the keyboard back is to fully uncharge the battery or open the ultrabook's lid and disconnect it. So the problem exists because of an incorrect hardware support on Linux, and AFAIK no one is solving it right now. I'll buy another brand next time and i don't recommend this Lenovo ultrabook to anyone.

Comment: As of 2013-06-13 the bug is still active.

Comment: Now, this can be fixed by a BIOS update.

Answer (score 0):

I have a a brand new Lenovo idea pad u410 and Ubuntu 12.04 is working now for me.  I'm new too, but from what I've learned so far, check into the graphics card on it.

I have a Nvidia GE610M and it is not recognized by Ubuntu....yet.  This is my challenge for today.  Not sure if you are new well, but if so, I would also recommend schooling yourself before hand on the installation process to make sure it goes nice and smooth the first time.  Wasn't so for me and although I have learned a great deal, it has taken some time.  Good luck!